# File not found dependency error while running react native ios app

Tags: ios, node.js, reactjs, react-native

So I wanted to install a dependency using npm which is `react-native-router-flux`, but since it wasn't working due to the compatibility versions with react & react-native, it was breaking my project app. So I removed it from the `package.json` file.

Tried removing it by doing:

`npm uninstall --save react-native-router-flux`

Even tried to remove it manually from the package.json file, but for some reason, now it looks like my whole project is broken due to that.
Now whenever I do `npm start`

This is what is being displayed in my terminal:

```
error: bundling: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/marian-mac/Documents/dev/example/myapp/node_modules/react-native-router-flux/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/ActivityIndicator/ActivityIndicator.js'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:634:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:502:33)
    at Module._readSourceCode (/Users/marian-mac/Documents/dev/example/myapp/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/Module.js:200:29)
    at Module._getCacheProps (/Users/marian-mac/Documents/dev/example/myapp/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/Module.js:420:29)
    at Module._readFromTransformCache (/Users/marian-mac/Documents/dev/example/myapp/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/Module.js:376:29)
    at Module.readCached (/Users/marian-mac/Documents/dev/example/myapp/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/Module.js:363:25)
    at Promise.resolve.then (/Users/marian-mac/Documents/dev/example/myapp/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:167:29)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
Bundling `index.ios.js`  94.0% (2941/3033)
```

I tried to rm -rf /node_modules 100 times and npm install another 100 times and this keeps failing and failing, I can't understand where is trying to access that file! if it was removed!!!

This is my package.json now:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "native-base": "^2.1.3",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-native": "0.44.0",
    "react-native-flags": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "jest": "19.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Is also throwing WARNINGS for versions and other things too:

```
npm WARN native-base-shoutem-theme@0.1.3 requires a peer of react@>=15.1.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @shoutem/animation@0.8.10 requires a peer of react@^15.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-static-container@1.0.1 requires a peer of react@^0.13.0 || ^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 but none was installed.
```

This is being thrown for native-base dependency:

```
 UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@^0.13.0 || ^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0
```

Can anyone help me? this is driving me crazy, been 'fighting' with this for hours now and I can't continue with my app.

Thanks in advance.

---

## EDIT:


After changing some versions for react, react-native and native-base. Still having warnings and looks like the packager is trying to access a react-native file within react-native-route-flux.

1) This is my current package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "native-base": "^2.1.3",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.3",
    "react-native": "^0.43.0",
    "react-native-flags": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "jest": "19.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

2) These are the warnings:

```
npm WARN react-native@0.43.4 requires a peer of react@16.0.0-alpha.6 but none was installed.
npm WARN native-base-shoutem-theme@0.1.3 requires a peer of react@>=15.1.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @shoutem/animation@0.8.10 requires a peer of react@^15.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-static-container@1.0.1 requires a peer of react@^0.13.0 || ^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-test-renderer@16.0.0-alpha.6 requires a peer of react@^16.0.0-alpha.6 but none was installed.
```

Also throws some UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY on native-base:

```
├─┬ native-base@2.1.3
│ ├─┬ @shoutem/animation@0.8.10
│ │ ├── hoist-non-react-statics@1.2.0
│ │ └── lodash@4.17.4
│ ├── blueimp-md5@2.7.0
│ ├── clamp@1.0.1
│ ├─┬ color@0.11.4
│ │ ├── clone@1.0.2
│ │ ├─┬ color-convert@1.9.0
│ │ │ └── color-name@1.1.2
│ │ └── color-string@0.3.0
│ ├─┬ fs-extra@2.1.2
│ │ └── jsonfile@2.4.0
│ ├── lodash@4.11.2
│ ├── native-base-shoutem-theme@0.1.3
│ ├── print-message@2.1.0
│ ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@^15.0.0
│ ├── react-native-drawer@2.3.0
│ ├── react-native-easy-grid@0.1.7
│ ├── react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view@0.2.7
│ ├─┬ react-native-scrollable-tab-view@0.7.4
│ │ ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@^0.13.0 || ^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0
│ │ └── react-static-container@1.0.1
│ ├── react-native-vector-icons@4.0.1
│ ├─┬ react-tween-state@0.1.5
│ │ └─┬ raf@3.3.2
│ │   └── performance-now@2.1.0
│ └── tween-functions@1.2.0
├─┬ UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@16.0.0-alpha.3
```

And in console when run, throws the red screen error in the simulator from XCode saying:

`No Dimension set for key window`

Looks it's a [known issue](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/1832) according to his github. But damn, I don't want react-native-router-flux anymore, I don't even have it in my package.json nor installed and is still causing trouble, this dependency is a virus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you face such kind situation just be cool and think what all other third parties got installed when the core third party was installed. I faced the similar issue while playing with `react-native-router-flux` and its stable version is  `v3.38.0`.

From the above question it seems `@shoutem/animation@0.8.10` and `react-static-container@1.0.1` came with the `react-native-router-flux` lib. and the other package i.e `native-base` is compatible with `react@>=15.1.0`

so i arose to the conclusion, remove `@shoutem` and `react-static-container` from node modules. In case there is still the error then i am damn sure the error is because of the native base. Remove `native base` completely from the project and wait for `native base` to update up to the latest version of `react`.

Try the above things and please share the progress as this can help others too.

Note 1: Whenever you see warning while installing packages please don't ignore those warning as they might be destroying the functionality of some package.

To update the package using `npm install package-name@x.y`, where x.y is the version number you want to install.

Note 2: To install packages `yarn` is preferred.

Below are the dependencies updated or installed with `react-native-router-flux`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-native": "^0.41.2",
    "react-native-experimental-navigation": "0.26.x",
    "react-native-tabs": "^1.0.9",
    "react-static-container": "1.0.1"
  },
```

As you can see `react-static-container` is inherited from `react-native-router-flux` and the other errors are because of `native-base`, see the below dependencies provided by `native-base` .

```
"dependencies": {
    "@shoutem/animation": "^0.8.9",
    "native-base-shoutem-theme": "0.1.3",
    "blueimp-md5": "^2.5.0",
    "clamp": "^1.0.1",
    "color": "~0.11.1",
    "fs-extra": "^2.0.0",
    "lodash": "~4.11.1",
    "print-message": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "0.1.7",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "0.2.7",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.7.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "~4.0.0",
    "react-tween-state": "^0.1.5",
    "tween-functions": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.3.0"
  },
```

Cheers :)

Comment: thanks!! i will try it out in a few hours, i just need to sleep some more, fought with that until 3am. thanks again for taking ur time! i will keep u updated.

Comment: Tested it, and even though those warnings are from native-base, it keeps throwing me the no such file or directory for react-native-router-flux, and i still can't figure out why, if it's uninstalled, not even using it in my project, why is it trying to get that file? :S 
Before i installed react-native-router-flux, i was able to work just fine with the package.json i had containing native-base, etc. That's why i know that dependency screwed up my entire project.

Comment: There are two options either remove native-base or change version of react.

Comment: Yea, too bad because native-base had a lot of good component i'm using. Right now my react version is the "16.0.0-alpha.6". Can you help me on depending what i want to use, the react, react-native and native-base combo to be fully supported without warnings? should i really use react 15.0.0?

Comment: "native-base": "^0.5.11", "react": "15.4.1","react-native": "0.39.0",

Comment: previous one would be too old , try this :- "react": "^16.0.0-alpha.3",
    "react-native": "^0.43.0", "native-base": "^2.1.3"

Comment: You did not completely upgrade react-native,please tell me steps you used to upgrade react-native?

Comment: Oh, i might be missing something. I tried:
`rm -rf /node_modules`
`npm uninstall --save react`
`npm uninstall --save react-native`
`npm uninstall --save native-base`

Then went to the package.json and added them manually since 
`npm install --save react@16.0.0-alpha.3` was throwing me an error. So i added all those, and run again `npm install` to install everything.

Comment: what you can do is install react-native first by running npm install react-native@^0.43.0 then you will get error for react and then add react to that version what the error is asking you to do. After doing all this run: react-native upgrade

Comment: please do not touch package.json. In the above comment add --save to every command

Comment: But from react-native ^0.43.0, node installed react version ^15.5.4 instead of 16.0.0-alpha.6. Do you know why?

Comment: that react package comes along with react native...what's the progress?

Comment: Still couldn't make it work, although i did a react-native upgrade, changed a lot of files in my XCode file, and XCode was throwing compiling error for `React/RCTLog.h file not found`. So now i'm trying to clean packager cache and start over again. I think i got a lot of old garbage and that's why it keeps failing and failing.

Comment: These are the dependencies i am using in my project "native-base": "^0.5.11", "react": "15.4.1","react-native": "0.39.0"

Comment: Thanks i will try those! and you had no issues with it? no warnings? another question, the `react-native upgrade` has to be called after installing all those 3 versions, right?

Comment: yeah it worked for me. react-native upgrade is called after running react-native command and thereafter react command. Firstly remove native base then do all these steps.

Comment: omg it works now! after cleaning all the cache and stuff, working with latest react 16.0.0-alpha.6, react-native ^0.44.0 and native-base ^2.1.3, still had some UNMET PEER DEPENDENCIES errors but it works, at least i could get rid of that annoying router-flux error and everything related to it! Thanks for taking your time, Codesingh!

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install react-native-reanimated 
react-native-gesture-handler 
react-native-screens 
react-native-safe-area-context 
@react-native-community/masked-view
```